# run jQuery code above jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am newbie in jQuery and just want to learn is this possible to place jquery code above jquery cdn file .. this is what i tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('this worked')
         });
      </script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

this is not worked because it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: You'll have to include jQuery before actually trying to use it. Swap places

Comment: add jquery library in head tag

Comment: i knew that but is this possible by any way to place jquery code above jquery file

Comment: @user3681048 no you cannot since $ is a syntax that is define in  jquery file only

Comment: Anything is possible, adding `async` or `defer` would probably work, but it's a bad idea, just move the scripts.

Comment: @adeneo any example ?

Comment: Not really, and `defer` probably doesn't work with inline scripts either, when I think about it.

Comment: it wont work , just place the code after the jquery.js, it will still bootstrap and return the alert when the document is really ready

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to use `jQuery`, you have to include it first.

The `jQuery` library adds `jQuery` and `$` global objects that you refer in your code to.

Answer (score -1):

try to use

```
window.onload = function() {
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
    alert("Yeah!");
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("Doesn't Work");
}
```

}